# Configure firewalld for OpenVPN (server-bridge) in Fedora 20

Tags: linux, firewall, openvpn, fedora-20, firewalld

I've installed an OpenVPN server (server-bridge) on Fedora 20, but I cannot get it to work. I'm almost sure that It's a firewall issue.

I'm trying to connect from an OSX client, but I can connect (just connect to VPN server, without access to anything) before the bridge is configured in server, however once I configure the bridge interface (using [this](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernet-bridging.html#linuxscript) script), then I cannot connect anymore. I've configured it as server-bridge, following these HOW-TOs from [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Openvpn) and [OpenVPN Ethernet-Bridge](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernet-bridging.html).

The firewall config is explained using iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i tap0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

However, in Fedora 20, by default, It's installed firewalld, so, Can anyone tell me the equivalent commands using `firewall-cmd` ? I read the [firewalld guide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD), but It's not clear to me how to achieve it (I'm a developer, no SysAdmin).

I know that I can install iptables, but I want it to work with firewalld.

**UPDATE:** After some reading on `firewall-cmd` man page, I tried to apply the previous commands using `--passthrough`option, that is:

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

The commands are successfully executed, but It doesn't work, I also tried to use `eb` instead of `ipv4` with the same result.

The `ifconfig` output is something like:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.40  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::c9:aff:fe02:d953  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:c9:09:02:d9:53  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11276  bytes 1374285 (1.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 899  bytes 240110 (234.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::c9:afa:fe02:d953  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 03:c9:0a:02:d9:53  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13548  bytes 1942379 (1.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1162  bytes 269258 (262.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 117  base 0xc000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 16436
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 6883  bytes 2061608 (1.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6883  bytes 2061608 (1.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

p2p0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::9831:16ff:fe81:3658  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9a:3b:16:84:36:58  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tap0: flags=4355<UP,BROADCAST,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d6:6c:20:12:f3:b6  txqueuelen 100  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.41  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::9a5b:16ff:fe81:3658  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 98:3b:11:81:36:58  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2643  bytes 230523 (225.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5512  bytes 1726039 (1.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my original question is:

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

Then, if you execute:

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent  --direct --get-all-passthroughs
```

You'll get this:

```
ipv4 -A INPUT -i tap0 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 -A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

However there is still something wrong, I cannot connect to the VPN server, so any idea/clue will be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

firewalld has some services already pre-configured which can be seen with:

```
firewall-cmd --get-services
```

(Configuration file /usr/lib/firewalld/services/openvpn.xml)

If you see openvpn as already available service you can enable it with:

```
firewall-cmd --add-service openvpn
```

Comment: I've already do that, the problem is not OpenVPN service, but the config of tap and bridge (br) network interfaces in the firewalld.